# low performance after update form 19.04 to 19.10

Tags: gnome, performance, 19.10

after updating form 19.04 to 19.10 gnome hangs many times even on simple operations and make me to refresh it .
CPU is always hot and fan has to work continuously.
top out put:

```
 9074 sorush    20   0 3636796 262496  59492 S   8.0   3.3  18:20.12 gnome-shell                                                                                                                            
 7991 sorush    20   0  610172 100252  66752 S   4.3   1.2   6:23.03 Xorg                                                                                                                                   
13320 sorush    20   0 2336336 630540  81020 S   3.7   7.8   0:11.83 MongoDB Compass                                                                                                                        
27039 sorush    20   0 1938872 217112  54976 S   3.3   2.7   3:02.41 Telegram                                                                                                                               
 9538 sorush    20   0  507324  56268  25832 S   2.3   0.7   0:12.62 guake                                                                                                                                  
13141 sorush    20   0 1375032 176232  82424 S   2.3   2.2   0:03.54 MongoDB Compass                                                                                                                        
  290 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1.3   0.0   1:01.47 irq/130-ELAN120                                                                                                                        
11154 sorush    20   0 4394104 275044  36804 S   1.3   3.4   1:01.40 Microsoft.Pytho                                                                                                                        
17018 sorush    20   0 1019732  88824  24468 S   1.3   1.1   3:18.17 persepolis                                                                                                                             
15693 sorush    20   0 3889772 415896 116040 S   1.0   5.2  10:51.27 firefox-bin                                                                                                                            
12083 sorush    20   0   15476   4560   3672 R   0.7   0.1   0:02.29 top                                                                                                                                    
16353 sorush    20   0 2802884 192644  70756 S   0.7   2.4   3:12.85 Web Content                                                                                                                            
    1 root      20   0  167404   8824   6392 S   0.3   0.1   0:22.76 systemd                                                                                                                                
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:20.50 rcu_sched                                                                                                                              
  609 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:10.32 irq/132-iwlwifi                                                                                                                        
  786 sorush    20   0 2672748 251568 107908 S   0.3   3.1   2:55.50 Web Content                                                                                                                            
  824 sorush    20   0 2501952 168128 120280 S   0.3   2.1   0:08.63 Web Content
```

````
Tasks: 336 total,   1 running, 331 sleeping,   0 stopped,   4 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.6 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 96.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7845.1 total,    317.1 free,   5409.6 used,   2118.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   1694.2 free,    353.8 used.   1769.0 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                
 9074 sorush    20   0 3634420 257076  54120 S   7.6   3.2  26:19.27 gnome-shell                                                                                                                            
13320 sorush    20   0 2359148 611792  67512 S   5.0   7.6   5:14.49 MongoDB Compass                                                                                                                        
 7991 sorush    20   0  601076  89448  71064 S   3.7   1.1   9:20.88 Xorg                                                                                                                                   
13141 sorush    20   0 1343792 154876  68544 S   2.7   1.9   2:47.68 MongoDB Compass                                                                                                                        
 9538 sorush    20   0  870464  66436  32532 S   2.3   0.8   0:22.72 guake                                                                                                                                  
  290 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   1.7   0.0   1:30.88 irq/130-ELAN120                                                                                                                        
17018 sorush    20   0 1019732  86324  21968 S   1.3   1.1   4:33.28 persepolis                                                                                                                             
27039 sorush    20   0 2366300 272208  57188 S   1.3   3.4   5:53.90 Telegram                                                                                                                               
19588 sorush    20   0 7120764   1.1g  75456 S   1.0  14.4   5:27.51 java                                                                                                                                   
  824 sorush    20   0 2471424 135600  84048 S   0.7   1.7   0:29.46 Web Content                                                                                                                            
 1342 mongodb   20   0 1031272  39568  13304 S   0.7   0.5   1:27.50 mongod                                                                                                                                 
 2416 root      20   0 1790164  16456   3668 S   0.7   0.2   0:21.35 dockerd                                                                                                                                
12713 sorush    20   0 2532164 174972 117032 S   0.7   2.2   0:12.95 Web Content                                                                                                                            
16353 sorush    20   0 2827704 205704  94752 S   0.7   2.6   4:05.40 Web Content                                                                                                                            
29440 sorush    20   0  165624   6328   5692 S   0.7   0.1   0:10.86 ibus-engine-sim                                                                                                                        
    1 root      20   0  167404   8708   6364 S   0.3   0.1   0:32.64 systemd                                                                                                                                
   11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:28.07 rcu_sched   ```
````

Comment: What did you try to fix it? Please run `top´ in a terminal to find top cpu using process, and update your question with that information. You can just copy the 10 or so lines and paste them into the question.

Comment: None of those seems to use much of the cpu .. could we have the top lines and headers  from top too ?

Comment: aaded that i think it may be for apps that fill my ram too much

Comment: dont you have any idea ??